# How would I code a statement that will choose 5 random frames out of 12 in Flash ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, random

I'm sure this question has been asked a million times in a million ways, but I would appreciate the help anyway. I am working on a Flash Mastermind clone and have a movie clip with 12 colored "pegs" and a "hole" image. How would I code a statement that will pick five random frames and not just the first five frames? I have the barest idea, but I'm not entirely sure if it's right:

```
var totalColors:Number = 12;
var maxColors:Number = 5;
var chosenColors:Array:

for(var i:Number = 1; i<totalColors; i++)
{
    chosenColors[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*totalColors)+1
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

[image: Movie Clip Colors]

Please note that the movieclip has been rearranged since I wrote this; I moved the first frame - the "hole" to another layer.

EDIT: Pan has helped a lot since I first asked this question. To test it I decided to expand on my Bejeweled clone code. I added five more shapes to the original 7. At first I thought the line "newPiece.type = Math.ceil(Math.random() * chosenColors.length);" inside the loop, so I commented the quoted line, which was outside of the j loop and part of the original code, and replaced it with this:

```
newPiece.type = chosenColors[j];
```

I am very sorry if this seems elementary to some; I am not the strongest programmer, especially when making games. I am far better at ASP.NET and UI design, but game development has always appealed to me for some weird, possibly insane reason. Anyway, here is part of the method for creating a new jewel. The two for loops are pan's code for choosing seven random frames out of twelve. Unfortunately, the movie still picks the first seven frames from the movie clip.

```
//i goes through all of the possible colors and adds them to the temp array
for (var i:uint = 1; i <= newPiece.totalFrames; i++)
{
    temp.push(i);
}

//j chooses seven colors out of the array of all possibilities
for (var j:int = 0; j < numPieces; j++)
{
    //index is the frame that has been chosen randomly
    var index:int = int(Math.random() * temp.length);
    chosenColors.push(j);
    chosenColors[j] = temp[index];

    //remove the index
    temp.splice(index, 0);
}

newPiece.type = Math.ceil(Math.random() * chosenColors.length);
```

Again, if I've confused anyone with my bad code to English translation, here is an image of my running game and its Jewel movieclip so you will hopefully see what I mean.

[image: Running Game & MovieClip]

Answer (score 1):

```
var totalColors:Number = 12;
var maxColors:Number = 5;   
var chosenColors:Array = [];
var temp:Array = [];

for(var i:Number = 1; i <= totalColors; i++)
{
    temp.push(i);
}

for (var j:int = 0; j < maxColors; j++)
{

   var index:int = int(Math.random()*temp.length);
   chosenColors[j] = temp[index];

   //remove the index
   temp.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: I have implemented your code in a working Bejeweled clone I made earlier. I have no compile time or runtime errors as long as I keep this line in your second for loop: but it's not limiting how many types of gems can be used. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What do you mean " limiting how many types of gems can be used"?